# Why aren't my if statements inside the for loops working properly?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do a w3resource.com exercise and my if statements inside the for loops aren't being respected(the code inside the if statement is running even if the condition isn't true). Please help me

I've already tried to replace the for loops with while loops and the problem persisted. I've tried to see what's wrong with my if statements but I couldn't find anything.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

void findAndPrintThe3LargestElements(int array[], int arraySize)
{
    int largestNumbers[] = { array[0], array[0], array[0] };
    for (int nextIndexNumber = 1; nextIndexNumber < arraySize; ++nextIndexNumber)
    {
        if (array[nextIndexNumber] > largestNumbers[0])
            largestNumbers[0] = array[nextIndexNumber];
    }


    for (int nextIndexNumber = 1; nextIndexNumber < arraySize; ++nextIndexNumber)
    {
        if (array[nextIndexNumber] > largestNumbers[1] && array[nextIndexNumber] != largestNumbers[0]);
        {
            largestNumbers[1] = array[nextIndexNumber];
        }
    }

    for (int nextIndexNumber = 1; nextIndexNumber < arraySize; ++nextIndexNumber)
    {
        if (array[nextIndexNumber] > largestNumbers[2] && array[nextIndexNumber] != largestNumbers[0] &&
            array[nextIndexNumber] != largestNumbers[1]);
        {
            largestNumbers[2] = array[nextIndexNumber];
        }
    }

    std::cout << "The three largest numbers in the array are: " << largestNumbers[0] << ", " << largestNumbers[1]
        << ", " << largestNumbers[2] << ".";
}

int main()
{
    int array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    int arraySize = std::size(array);
    findAndPrintThe3LargestElements(array, arraySize);
    return 0;
}
```

The program is not working properly, outputting the wrong numbers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: _"the code inside the if statement is running even if the condition isn't true"_ Well, computers don't do that, so your assumption must be incorrect!

Comment: @Gustavo Dias The code does not make sense. At least it is unclear what is the meaning of the variable  int timesRun{ 0 };

Comment: Sorry about the inconsistencies, I'm a begginer. I've used the variable timesRun{ 0 }; to count how many times the for loops are run.

Comment: @Gustavo Dias I do not understand what you are trying to achieve using this variable especially in the condition (array[nextIndexNumber] + timesRun) != largestNumbers[0])

Comment: Sorry that variable indeed didn't make sense in the code. I've edited and removed it. Initially my code didn't have that, i've put it trying to fix it. Now it's the original code. But the if statements still run when not expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second and third loop you put semicolon after the `if`:

```
if (<condidion>);
{
    <your code>
}
```

so effectively the condition has empty block and the block with your code is always executed. It is more visible like this:

```
if (<condition>)
    ;    // no operation here

{        // always executed
    <your code>
}
```